# What quark mass to use in energy conservation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, energy-conservation, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I am looking into energy conservation within decay processes and am getting confused about which mass I need to use for quarks. For example to determine if the reaction:
$$\mu^{-}\rightarrow \nu_\mu+q +\bar q$$
takes place we need:
$$m_\mu \gt 2m_q$$
but what mass/energy should I use for $m_q$? From what I have read the constituent mass seems the most sensible but I am not sure and sources seem to be lacking in this area. Please can someone explain.

Comment: The Feynman rules derive from the Lagrangian. What's the mass written in your Lagrangian?

Comment: Mass-energy relations always refer to the on-shell mass, which need not be well defined for a quark.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am coming at this from undergrad particle physics course point of view rather then rigorous QFT, so sorry I do not even know the Lagrangian you are talking about. (Although I will try to look it up :) )

Comment: @ACuriousMind I tried looking but still can't find a definite answer. I am starting to get the impression that it is not as simple as using a single mass $m_q$ but the energies of *all possible* bound states have to be considered. Is this correct?

Comment: Quarks *never* appear as initial or final states in a physical reaction. For example, the conservation of energy for $\pi ^+ \to \mu ^+ + \nu_\mu$ reads $$m_\pi = E_\mu + E_\nu,$$ not $$E_u + E_\overline d = E_\mu + E_\nu.$$

Comment: For future reference and for anyone interested: I found the following resource useful: Commins, E.D. and Bucksbaum, P.H., 1983. *Weak interactions of leptons and quarks*. cambridge university press. (p147)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [word constituent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_quark) is a clue:

> According to the Feynman diagrams, constituent quarks seem to be 'dressed' current quarks, i.e. current quarks surrounded by a cloud of virtual quarks and gluons. This cloud in the end explains the large constituent-quark masses.
>
> Definition: Constituent quarks are valence quarks for which the correlations for the description of hadrons by means of gluons and sea-quarks are put into effective quark masses of these valence quarks.
>
> The effective quark mass is called constituent quark mass. Hadrons consist of 'glued' constituent quarks. The use of positions for the light constituent quarks is not exactly unproblematic in the description of hadrons.

So it is a quark mass definition useful when considering quarks in the bag of hadrons.

Valence [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark)

> The quarks that determine the quantum numbers of hadrons are called valence quarks;

.....

> Two terms are used in referring to a quark's mass: current quark mass refers to the mass of a quark by itself, while constituent quark mass refers to the current quark mass plus the mass of the gluon particle field surrounding the quark.[71] These masses typically have very different values. Most of a hadron's mass comes from the gluons that bind the constituent quarks together,

The current  quark masses are part of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, as written in the particle table and are used in calculations with the Lagrangians .

The reaction you are studying could not have constituent masses because the quarks are not in a bound hadron, thus it has to be the current quark masses written in the particle table.

The smallest constituent mass is  336 MeV (model dependent) . The mass of the [muon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon) is 105 MeV.  No choice

The charged pion, the smallest hadron, composed also, as in your reaction, out of a quark and an antiquark, has a mass of 139 MeV, so in actuality your problem is not a description of a physical system, since an 105 MeV muon cannot emit bound quarks of 139 . So even if the energetics work with the current masses the two quarks cannot be a bound pion and since quarks are never free this reaction cannot go by itself. It could go in a quark gluon plasma, even in a secondary interaction with a heavy nucleus.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, please can you clarify your state that 'it has to be the current quark masses'... Are you saying that if $m_\mu \gt 2 m_q$ where $m_q$ is a current quark mass then the reaction will occur? Or are you saying that if $\mu_\mu \gt m_\pi$ (where $m_\pi$ is the mass of a pion) then the reaction will occur.

Comment: The reaction cannot occur for a muon in space because even though energetically one could have two free current mass quarks , and that is the mass to use in a simple diagram calculation, the  quark antiquark pair cannot exist free, and  the energy ( center of mass the only energy available is the muon mass) available cannot make a pion.

Comment: If a muon fell into a quark gluon plasma ( cosmological times) then it could happen because the quark would find an antiquark to bind with and the antiquark a quark, conserving energy from picking it up from the quark gluon plasma.  One cannot change the mass of the muon, and it is smaller than the pion one